# Probability with dependent Bernoulli and normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory

**Question.** Let $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac12\right)$ and $Y\sim\text{Norm}\left(2(X-\frac12),1\right)$. Calculate $\mathbb{P}(X=1\mid Y\geqslant 1).$

As you can see, the random variable $X$ is nested into the expectation of the normal distribution. I have never seen a situation like this before.

My try:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=1\mid Y\geqslant 1)=\mathbb{P}(Y\geqslant 1 \mid X=1)\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=1)}{\mathbb{P}(Y\geqslant 1)}$$
and
$$\mathbb{P}(Y\geqslant 1\mid X=x)=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(s-2(x-1/2))^2/2}\,ds=\int_{2-2x}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}\,du$$
I honestly have no idea how to proceed.
Could someone provide help?

Comment: Should not you write $Y|X=x$ instead of $Y$ in the first line?

Comment: @Shashi this is exactly how it appeared on an old exam.

Comment: Okay, then I don't know what it means. I hope someone else with more knowledge can help us to understand what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it your way, we get
$$\Bbb P (Y\geq 1 | X = 1) = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}\;du = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\Bbb P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$$
\begin{align}\Bbb P(Y\geq 1) &= \Bbb P(Y\geq 1 | X = 1)\Bbb P (X = 1) + \Bbb P(Y\geq 1 | X = 0)\Bbb P(X = 0)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} + (1 - \Phi(2))\cdot \frac{1}{2} \\
&\approx 26.1375\%
\end{align}
So you end up with
$$\Bbb P(X = 1 | Y\geq 1) \approx \frac{25\%}{26.1375\%} \approx 95.65\%$$
which is exactly the same as in zoli's answer!

**EDIT:** Just in case, by $\Phi$, I mean
$$\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\;dz$$

Comment: I don't know why I got confused, but at some point I didn't recognise I could just use the mean 1 for $Y$ while calculating $\mathbb{P}(Y\geqslant 1\mid X=1)$. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Can I ask one more question? How would we calculate $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$?

Comment: You can do something similar. Knowing that $\Bbb E[X] = 0.5$ and $\Bbb E[Y] = 0$ (by symmetry of $yf_Y(y)$), you can see that $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = \Bbb E[XY]$. I think you can take it from there!

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of $Y$ is $N(-1,1)$ with probability $\frac12$ and $N(1,1)$ with the same probability. So the pdf of $Y$,
$$f_Y(y)=\frac12\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(e^{\frac{(y+1)^2}2}+e^{\frac{(y-1)^2}2}\right).$$
So

$$P(Y\geq 1)=\frac12\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_1^{\infty}\left(e^{\frac{(y+1)^2}2}+e^{\frac{(y-1)^2}2}\right)\ dy.$$

And

$$P(X=i\cap Y\geq 1)=P(Y\geq 1\mid X=1)\frac12=\frac12\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_1^{\infty}e^{\frac{(y-1)^2}2}\ dy.$$

So

$$P(X=1\mid Y\geqslant 1)=\frac{P(X=1\cap Y\geq 1)}{P(Y\geq 1)}=\frac{\int_1^{\infty}e^{\frac{(y-1)^2}2}\ dy}{\int_1^{\infty}\left(e^{\frac{(y+1)^2}2}+e^{\frac{(y-1)^2}2}\right)\ dy}.$$

Comment: Great answer! Just a minor thing that may confuse the OP, but the constant in $f_Y(y)$ should be $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}$, and similarly in the other distribution functions.

Comment: @bames: No: the constant is $\frac14$. $\frac12$ comes form $N(.,.)$ and the other $\frac12$ comes form the probability that $X=1$ or $0$.

Comment: The constant in the normal distribution function is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Multiplying by the probability that $X=1$, we get $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}$. This should be obvious, since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}\;dz = \sqrt{\pi}$...

Comment: @bames: THX a lot. I've corrected my answer.